# Printing list to CSV or txt on new lines

Tags: python, sql, csv, text, output

I'm trying to export some data, taken from an sql database, to a txt- or csv-file. The print statement:

```
for x in range(len(data)):
        print(data[x])
```

this outputs what I want, every element in a new line

```
(1, 90, Netherlands, male)
(2,  50, Germany, Female)
```

etc.. Now, when I try putting this to a text file it just adds everything in 1 long line, all the info pasted behind each other just like a regular `print(data)` command.

I posted my code below so you get the context

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM batch'
c.execute(sql)
data = c.fetchall()
list1 = []
addDataToList = list1.append(data)
for x in range(len(data)):
    print(data[x])

    with open('Rapport.txt', mode="w") as output:
    for x in range(len(data)):
        output.write("\n" .join(str(data[x])))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every element on a new line

Then try this

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM batch'
c.execute(sql)
data = c.fetchall()
list1 = []
addDataToList = list1.append(data)
# construct output
outputString = ''
for x in range(len(data)):
   outputString = outputString + str(data[x]) + '\n'
# write output to file
with open('Rapport.txt', mode="w") as output:
   output.write(outputString)
```

By the way, you're writing to the same file `x^2` number of times, with only the last write being visible as you keep overwriting the last write. You should be careful with nested `for` statements. See the example below:

```
data = ['1', '90', 'Netherlands', 'male']
result = ''
for x in range(len(data)):
    print(data[x])

    #with open('Rapport.txt', mode="w") as output:
    for x in range(len(data)):
        #output.write("\n" .join(str(data[x])))
        result = result + (data[x] + ' ')

print (str(result))
```

Output:

> 1 90 Netherlands male 1 90 Netherlands male 1 90 Netherlands male 1 90 Netherlands male

Comment: Yes, it's only for a status rapport "at the moment" it's meant to overwrite the file and only have the last write visible! thanks for the answer!

Comment: See my edit above. Have another think about it, it does not seem right to me.

Comment: that is a helpful edit! I learned a lot experimenting with your info! the code you posted about 1 or 2 edits ago worked perfectly!

Comment: Yes I see the issue. The open( ) function takes a second parameter defining mode. In your example you're using `w`, which opens for writing and erases any existing data. You'll want to use `a` here, otherwise you'll just end up with the last line. A better option would be to build the output string and just do a single `write()` call.

Comment: I have made an edit to create a output string, which gets constructed in the `for` loop, then gets written to file just once. Now we're doing just `1` write, instead of your original code `x^2`

Answer (score 1):

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM batch'
c.execute(sql)
data = c.fetchall()
list1 = []
addDataToList = list1.append(data)
for x in range(len(data)):
    print(data[x])

with open('Rapport.txt', mode="w") as output:
    for x in range(len(data)):
        print(str(data[x]), file=output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `write` with `\n` to write content to each line.

**Ex:**

```
with open('Rapport.txt', mode="w") as output:
    for i in data:
        output.write("{0} \n".format(str(i)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! really usefull!